# Host errors after cross-compilation of Qt 5.9.2

Tags: c++, cross-compilation, qt

I've cross-compiled Qt 5.9.2 for Raspbian Stretch with the following setup:

git clone -b 5.9 git://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git
cd qt5
./init-repository
./configure -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi2-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=~/opt/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot ~/opt/sysroot -opensource -confirm-license -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -extprefix ~/opt/qt5pi -hostprefix ~/opt/qt5 -v -nomake examples -nomake tests -reduce-exports -no-pch
make
make install

No problem while configuring and building.
Then I set up QtCreator (3.5.1):

```
debugger: ~/opt/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb
compiler: ~/opt/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
qmake: ~/opt/qt5/bin/qmake
sysroot: ~/opt/sysroot
```

I've done this a lot of times in these years. But now, when I create a new QWidget project I get this error:

```
/home/mark/opt/qt5/mkspecs/features/toolchain.prf(70): system(execute) requires one or two arguments.
Project ERROR: Cannot run target compiler '/home/mark/opt/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++'. Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?
Error while parsing file /home/mark/Documenti/test2/test2.pro. Giving up.
```

The *-g++ file is exactly where it's expected to be, like in the compiler configuration under Tools menu.

Creating a QtQuick project leads to these other errors:

```
home/mark/opt/qt5/mkspecs/features/qmake_use.prf(6): 'take_first' is not a recognized replace function.
Project ERROR: Library '' is not defined.
Warnings while parsing QML type information of /home/mark/opt/qt5pi/qml/QtQuick.2:
/home/mark/opt/qt5pi/qml/QtQuick.2/plugins.qmltypes:1:24: Reading only version 1.1 parts.
/home/mark/opt/qt5pi/qml/QtQuick.2/plugins.qmltypes:10:5: Expected only Component and ModuleApi object definitions.

Warnings while parsing QML type information of /home/mark/opt/qt5pi/qml/QtQuick/Window.2:
/home/mark/opt/qt5pi/qml/QtQuick/Window.2/plugins.qmltypes:1:24: Reading only version 1.1 parts.
/home/mark/opt/qt5pi/qml/QtQuick/Window.2/plugins.qmltypes:10:5: Expected only Component and ModuleApi object definitions.

...continue for a lot of other modules
```

I never had such a problem - I don't know what those messages actually mean and how to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [you resolved the problem](https://forum.qt.io/topic/82604/qt-5-9-2-cross-compiled-host-errors) by upgrading and doing a clean build?

[This Qt 5.9 bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-62434) sounds strikingly similar and appeared to affect all cross-compilation targets including Raspberry Pi.

However, the fix was merged into the `5.9` branch on August 15th, a week before your post. One explanation could be that you had cloned the repo earlier and while troubleshooting over the course of a week had not been doing a corresponding `git submodule update` after each `git pull`. Note that `./init-repository` requires that you pass the `-f` flag if the submodules have already been init once.

Comment: Yes, it might be a good explanation of what happened.